# How to delete certain words from a word cloud in mathematica?

Tags: word-cloud

I generated word clouds from a text file in *Mathematica*. I was able to remove words with 5 or less characters from the cloud.

```
 fdp2 = StringReplace[fdp, 
 WordBoundary ~~ Repeated[WordCharacter, 5] ~~ WordBoundary -> ""]
 WordCloud[fdp2]
```

But there are still useless words in the cloud. How can I remove a specific word like "become" from a word cloud?

Comment: could you please provide code for `fdp`?

Comment: From a word cloud or from the string source? There is `StringDelete` now but you can proceed with your current method too, what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 7):

If you building a word cloud there are a few tricks. **First of all use DeleteStopwords**. Compare:

```
cat = Import["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat"];

{WordCloud[cat], WordCloud[DeleteStopwords[cat]]}
```

[image]

Yes, the right one much better, but now we see the next problem "cat" vs "cats". I usually use reduce to baseform:

```
Clear@base;
base[w_] := With[
   {tmp = WordData[w, "BaseForm", "List"]},
   If[(Head[tmp] === Missing) || tmp === {}, w, tmp[[1]]]];
SetAttributes[base, Listable];
```

I would also consider removing numbers (not a must though) and black-listing. For example Wikipedia pages often noisy with:

```
blackLIST = {"doi", "ed", "isbn", "pmid"};
```

I would also use `ScalingFunctions -> (#^s &)` where $0<s<5$ is a correction that emphasizes or deemphasizes word frequency-size visual (5 is a good number, could be more though). Here we go:

```
WordCloud[
 DeleteCases[
  base[TextWords[StringDelete[DeleteStopwords[ToLowerCase[cat]], 
  DigitCharacter ..]]],
  Alternatives @@ blackLIST],
 ScalingFunctions -> (#^.3 &)]
```

[image]